# Program or plugin for downloading database search results?

Tags: database, export, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I am doing a systematic literature review and am looking to download the results of my searches (in databases like ProQuest, Jstor, Web of Science, and Google Scholar) into text files or a spreadsheet (or another readable, searchable form) so I can review them later. Some of our searches have upwards of 10,000 results and that may complicate things. Are there any plugins or programs available that offer this service? I am currently using Mendeley to track my citations and am looking into whether similar software like Zotero or Endnote has a feature that exports database search results--but I've found nothing. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest free [Publish or Perish](https://harzing.com/resources/publish-or-perish) for Google Scholar. It allows for batch export of search results in various formats, and also provides nifty analytical tools for the publications metrics (H/G-index, citations-per-key_value, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you create a user account in Web of Science (WoS), you are able to save your search query as well as the search results. Your saved query in WoS is constantly updated when new matches occur. You are able to download the full bibliometric data (Title, Author, Abstract, Author name, Publication Year, Times cited, List of references) of all the records resulted by search query in 500 records per request. The downloaded format is .txt or .csv which you can import to excel. It is cumbersome for large sets but currently the only possible way. Here is the video showing the records download procedure: https://youtu.be/TqZZ5O3fiOk